# Django tokens being displayed as text

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am currently working on a Django project. I am having problem with the tokens on my HTML, they are being displayed as text.

The HTML for the page in question:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light tool-pattern-btn btn-action-pattern"
            onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)"><i class="material-icons left">keyboard_return</i>Go Back</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12">
        {% if submitted %}
        Employee included succefully!

        {% else %}
            <form action="{% url 'incluirPessoa' %}" method="post">
                <div class="card hoverable">
                    <div class="card-content exib-pattern">
                        <span class="card-title-home"><i class="material-icons left">add</i>New Employee</span>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12 l6">
                                <input ng-model="pessoa.name" maxlength="255" type="text" class="form-control" id="nome"
                                    name="nome" />
                                <label for="nome">Name:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s12 l4">
                                <input ng-model="pessoa.email" maxlength="255" type="text" class="form-control"
                                    id="nome" name="nome" />
                                <label for="nome">Email address:</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12 l3">
                                <input ng-model="pessoa.identidade" maxlength="255" type="text" class="form-control"
                                    id="identidade" name="identidade" />
                                <label for="id">identidade:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s12 l3">
                                <label for="id">Institute:</label>
                                <input ng-model="pessoa.institute" maxlength="255" type="text" class="form-control"
                                    id="instituto" name="instituto">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="col s12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light tool-pattern-btn green">
                                    <i class="material-icons left">add</i>Add</button>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        {% endif %}

    </div>

</div>
```

I have already read a couple of questions, but couldn't find any answer.